# Router logs show constant unknown port mapping (forwarding)?

Tags: router, port-forwarding, virus, trojan

Do I have a virus or trojan? Should I be worried? What’s going on here? I’m currently running Debian, and there are records like this for every day since these first records showed up. I coincidentally reformatted my hard drive yesterday, and reinstalled debian with an encrypted drive. Records from yesterday still showed up though.

```
2015/11/25 00:12:35 Notice  [IGD][2250]: Delete Port mapping (null):3074
2015/11/25 00:08:06 Notice  [IGD][2250]: Add Port mapping :3074 to 10.0.0.39:3074
2015/11/23 23:07:27 Notice  [IGD][2244]: Add Port mapping :59435 to 10.0.0.139:59435
2015/11/23 23:07:27 Notice  [IGD][2280]: Add Port mapping :59435 to 10.0.0.139:59435
2015/11/23 23:07:24 Notice  [IGD][2244]: Add Port mapping :4433 to 10.0.0.139:4433
2015/11/23 23:07:24 Notice  [IGD][2280]: Add Port mapping :4433 to 10.0.0.139:4433
2015/11/23 23:07:21 Notice  [IGD][2280]: Add Port mapping :59435 to 10.0.0.139:59435
2015/11/23 23:07:21 Notice  [IGD][2244]: Add Port mapping :59435 to 10.0.0.139:59435
```

Answer (score 2):

I googled `IGD`, or *Internet Gateway Device* Protocol, which brought me to `UPnP`, or *Universal Plug and Play*, which brought me to *the culprit, [**Deluge**](http://deluge-torrent.org), my torrent client*. It automatically forwards those ports for seeding whenever the download has finished. Just have to disable seeding which apparently deluge does not support completely. Time to switch torrent programs I guess.

Comment: [Transmission](http://www.transmissionbt.com) works very well for me, including proper use of uPnP ports.   It's available in the Debian Repos too.  (The port :3074 entry is for your XBox)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! It looks like it's between *Transmission* and [qBittorrent](http://www.qbittorrent.org/)... but I'll probably go with *qBittorrent* due to the familiar interface. @JakeGould Thanks! I'll keep that in mind for future questions/answers

Comment: Damn, I was going to say it sounds like UPnP but you beat me to it.